# Only can save part of data to database

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have

> models.py

```
......
class CatalogGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Scale(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name



class ProductsTbl(models.Model):
    model_number = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, unique=True,error_messages={'unique':"This model number has already been registered."})
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    material = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True, null=True)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    feature = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    release = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    suggest = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    cataloggroup = models.ManyToManyField(CatalogGroup)
    place = models.ManyToManyField(Place)
    scale = models.ManyToManyField(Scale)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    useredit = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_imagep_Product, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ''' On save, update timestamps '''

        if not self.id:
            self.created = timezone.now()

        return super(ProductsTbl, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
.....
```

and I need update the database if any user modified the data in the form, so I have:

> views.py

```
.......
@login_required
def edit_thing(request, slug):
# grab the object...
    thing = ProductsTbl.objects.get(slug=slug)
    if thing.user != request.user:
        raise Http404
# set the form we're using...
    form_class = ProductsTblForm
    if request.method == 'POST':
# grab the data from the submitted form
        form = form_class(data=request.POST,files=request.FILES,instance=thing)

        if form.is_valid():
            form = form.save(commit=False)
            form.useredit = request.user.username


            form.save()
            return redirect('thing_detail', slug=thing.slug)
# otherwise just create the form
    else:
        form = form_class(instance=thing)
# and render the template
    return render(request, 'things/edit_thing.html', {
        'thing': thing,
        'form': form,
    })
.........
```

however, after I submited the data, it has only part of data can save in database, those three data below can not be save

```
cataloggroup = models.ManyToManyField(CatalogGroup)
place = models.ManyToManyField(Place)
scale = models.ManyToManyField(Scale)
```

I do not know why these three data can not save in ??

and if I removed

> form = form.save(commit=False)

from the

> views.py

, the

> form.useredit = request.user.username

will not work, but can save those three data to database, however I have to let the useredit update to user who modified the data.

Answer (score 0):

I figure out how to do it,,,I add one more "form.save()" above ,,and it can save all the data

> views.py

```
....
if form.is_valid():

    form.save()
    form = form.save(commit=False)
    form.useredit = request.user.username

    form.save()
    return redirect('thing_detail', slug=thing.slug)
....
```